# Show only one window in taskbar per file in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, display-settings

In MS Excel 2010, under Options -> Advanced -> Display, there is a checkbox called "Show all windows in taskbar". As far as I can tell, this options is global for all files opened and local to the user.

Is it possible to force this setting on or off for a single workbook and have this setting follow the file?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it may be possible as the setting is wrote to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`'s key in the registry. e.g.:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Options
```

That means, as you already mentioned that this option is local for a current user and not for a workbook / file.

You can try to use following AutoExec macro in your Wokbook:

```
Sub AutoExec()
 ' To activate
 Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = True
  ' To de-activate
  'Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = False
End Sub
```

[EDITED] Please note the comment of [LPChip](https://superuser.com/users/311586/lpchip) about possibly unwanted setting's overwriting.

Comment: Good suggestion with the macro, but you should add that by doing so, the setting changes on the client, thus effectively it alters people's settings. Some might not like that.

Comment: @LPChip: Thank you for comment, I've edited according.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and the warning. Is it possible to work around that by returning the users setting to the previous state when closing the file?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to save the current state and set it back on closing!